# Can't find suitable Bistable/Latching 12V DPDT Relay

Tags: relay, 12v, dpdt, latching

I have a 12V actuator that is controlled by a 12V programmable timer. So my pulse is either power or no power. I am using a regular 12V DPDT relay which works fine.

However, I would like to use a Bistable relay so that I can turn off the power entirely (except for the timer of course) after the actuator is done extending/retracting.

My understanding of a Bistable relay is that it stays in it's last energized position even if it does not receive any power.

Based on that I bought several "Bistable/self-locking/latching" relays on ebay (Made in China) that claim to be "bistable/latching/self-locking".
These relays need a short trigger (like a momentary switch) to switch and stay in this position until triggered again.

BUT when power is removed entirely the relay switches back (reset). This is not how a bistable relay is suppose to work or am I wrong ????

Can someone tell me where I can get a relay like that (as cheap as possible of course)?
I found GE RR7 relays that are suppose to work like that but the ones I find are mostly remote controlled relays which I don't need. I am really having a hard time finding a 12V DPDT latching relay that stays in its last energized position even if power is removed entirely.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Have you checked that the part you received is actually a bistable relay? It must have a part number printed on it, and we don't know what part you have without a part number.

Comment: What do you mean by "remotely controlled relay"?  Can you give a make and part number for one?  In my experience, all relays can be, and frequently are "remote controlled".

Comment: Thanks for getting back with me. Here is one of the relays I bought. It says Bistable in the description but when it switches and I remove power entirely it switches back.                https://www.ebay.com/itm/264648948025       Thank you for your help.

Comment: And here is a link to one of the RR7 relays I found.  Thank you for your help.        https://www.kyleswitchplates.com/ge-rr7-low-voltage-remote-control-relay-switch